# Map/Transform linear function to exponent

Tags: functions, exponential-function

I have a slider:

```
min val. = 0
max val. = 20'000
step = 0.1
```

`min`, `max` values and `step` are `constants`.
On each step (thumb position change) slider returns a current value and a thumb position in % (see. img).

How can I transform the current returned value to make it grow exponentially like on the 2nd graphic - where 0 - 8'000 - take 80% of slider width.

Red graphic:

> On each step (thumb position change) slider returns a current value and a thumb position in % - current value grows linearly depending on the thumb position.

Green graphic:

> This is what I need. I can only use current thumb position and current slider value as a function arguments.

[image]

Comment: Does the slider thumb value need to equal 1 when the slider is at 20000, or just be very close to 1, i.e., 0.99?

Comment: It Will be equal 100%. I can't alter slider inner calculations (red graph) I can use only `current thumb position % and current slider value` for my function. Slider inner calculations = interpolation between thumb position and max, min values, so it is linear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try the following function

$$
f(x) = \alpha\tanh(\beta x)
$$

where the constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have been selected so that $f(8000) = 0.8$ and $f(20000) = 1$. The values for the constants were determined numerically to be

$$
\alpha = 1.00912774623104, \quad \beta = 0.000134853425544814
$$

Using these values the curve $y = f(x)$ for $x\in [0,20000]$ is given by the following figure.

[image]